# How to create retry connecting button? HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, button, refresh

The question is how to create a button that retries connection to a website. The non working is:

```
<a href="the page you are currently on">Retry/Refresh</a>
```

Comment: That should work; so should `javascript:location.reload()`. What behaviour are you seeing instead?

Comment: This seems to be working too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `window.location.reload(true)`

[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

Answer (score 0):

The working code should be:

```
<button onclick="retryConnect()">Retry</button>
<script>
function retryConnect(){
    location="retry.html";
}
</script>
```

Create a file called retry.html in the same directory, and write in it:

```
<p onload="loadPage()">Please wait...</p>

<script>
var delayLoad;

function loadPage() {
    delayLoad = setTimeout(showPage, 1000);
}

function showPage() {
  location="the previous page";
}
</script>
```

Comment: This question was suposed to help people who look for this on the search engines, I've asked a question and answered it because I've been a few times on questions like mine on stack which are not answered, yet

Comment: just one little comment. try emptying the cache when you reload just to be safe that the page is actually pulled from the server and not from browser's memory

Comment: catchiecop, for this is the delay ;)